Spring Boot 3 Actuator Info Endpoint GOAWAY
I have a number of Spring Boot services that ping the actuator info endpoint of another service to check for a field to change.
There are about 4 services pinging the one info endpoint every 30 seconds or so.
This worked fine in Spring Boot 2 but when we upgrade to Spring Boot 3 we noticed we randomly get a GOAWAY response when pinging it.
During this migration we did change from RestTemplate to WebClient which might be related.
I've done some searching and some pages say it relates to HTTP/2 vs 1.1.
Source 1
Source 2
I could adjust the code to force 1.1 but that feels like it shouldn't be needed just for pinging something like this.
Scheduled pinging code for reference:
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000, initialDelay = 60000)
public void pingInfoEndpoint() {
  // WebClient is injected as a bean in the class
  String someResponse = webClient
            .get()
            .uri("https://my-endpoint.com/actuator/info")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
  // Do stuff with response
}

Looking for either the cause of it or any suggestions on things to try to fix it.
Thanks!
